# URL-scheme details for Reminders application

Tags: macos, reminders, url

**Update**:

- [jeeyul's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/161968/28668) points out that **Reminders-related URL schemes are *undocumented***, which **would likely cause rejection of apps that use them when submitted to the macOS/iOS App Store**.

  - For personal  use, however, this wouldn't be an issue (except that undocumented behavior could change without notice).
- As of macOS 13 (Ventura), the `reminders:` scheme fundamentally doesn't work anymore - only `x-apple-reminderkit:` does.

---

The Reminders application understands the `x-apple-reminderkit:` <del>`reminders:`</del> URL scheme, so that you can invoke it, for instance, from Terminal as `open x-apple-reminderkit:` (use of `//` is optional), which simply opens the application with its default / last-saved state.

What I'm looking for is documentation of further elements of this scheme. Specifically, I want to construct URLs that allow me to do the following:

- open a specific list
- open a specific reminder

I've tried things like `x-apple-reminderkit:74771907-EA34-4848-A935-0C839AE123CC` using both list and reminder-item identifiers,<sup>[1]</sup> but to no avail.

See also:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html for a list of official URL schemes on both iOS and OSX
- https://superuser.com/questions/498943/directory-of-url-schemes-for-mac-apps provides good information on examining the schemes defined on a given machine.

---

[1] From the terminal (running a POSIX-compatible shell such as  `zsh` or `bash`), you can use the following command to *print all list* by name and identifier:

```
osascript -e $'tell application "Reminders" to repeat with lst in lists \n log {get name of lst, get id of lst} \n end repeat'
```

To print a single reminder's name and identifier, adapt the following example (use `list id "some-list-id"` in lieu of `first list`:

```
osascript -e $'tell application "Reminders" \n set rmnd to first reminder of first list \n log {get name of rmnd, get id of rmnd} \n end tell'
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update**:

- The **(partial) solution below no longer works** as of **macOS 13 (Ventura)**: The **`x-apple-reminder:`** scheme is no longer supported via `open` - even though individual *reminders* (as opposed to *lists*) still report their IDs as `x-apple-reminder://{some-guid}` via AppleScript, for instance.

---

[jeeyul's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/161968/28668) mentions `x-apple-reminder` as an alternative URL scheme.

While both `reminders://` and `x-apple-reminder://` work on OSX to merely *launch* the Reminders app, it turns out that the following works *only* with `x-apple-reminder://`, which shows **how to open (jump to) a specific *reminder***:

```
x-apple-reminder://{reminderId}
```

Example: from Terminal, open the *reminder* whose ID is `0BFDC528-306D-47A7-8E8F-895ACCDC6FFA`:

```
open x-apple-reminder://0BFDC528-306D-47A7-8E8F-895ACCDC6FFA
```

However, **doing the same for a reminder *list* does NOT work**.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the details of URL scheme.
However the scheme is `x-apple-reminder` not `reminders`
It can launch reminder app at least.

However the host and path rule is not revealed yet.
Reminder widget can open Reminder with specific `EKReminder`, 
So, there must be a scheme definition for it.

The scheme `x-apple-reminder` is undocumented, So using it should be rejected.

Comment: Thanks - curiously, for merely _launching_ the Reminders app on OSX, `reminders://` works just as well as `x-apple-reminder://` However, I've up-voted your answer for mentioning the latter, because it turns out that you can at least open specific reminders with it - see my [half-]answer.
Incidentally, that the Reminder widget can open an individual reminder doesn't necessarily mean that it's using a URL to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I found one tricks for proximity type reminders. 
I was looking for the way to find which proximity reminder triggered a shortcuts.

If a reminder is a due date type, it’s pretty easy.  Shortcuts filter offers complete or due date sort fiction and selecting the latest completion reminder is the one who triggered a shortcuts.

But if a proximity type reminder triggered a shortcuts, ios doesn’t offer such as “latest proximity  reminders”.

I spent several hours to find an alternative and figured out this way works.

Find Reminders where
  List is YOUR_LIST
  Sort by last modified date
  Order latest
  Limit on
  Get 1 reminder

This method works for me.

This is very useful if you have hundreds of proximity reminders and if you don’t want to make hundreds of shortcuts associated with each reminder.   This methods can also pass text data from note section of reminders to a shortcuts.

Thanks

Comment: Assumption is 1. List of reminders contains proximity type reminders only.   2. Shortcuts must be triggered immediately from reminder URL scheme.